# HTTPS doesnt work iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, https, ios9

Same error appears even I am using HTTPS

App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file. gete The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.

any help?

Comment: Did you even read the error message?  You are trying to load a resource over HTTP, but your App Transport Security policy requires that resources are loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: I am using HTTPS to load data from server the rquest url start with https and the server api also under https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just paste this into your `info.plist` file and you are good to go. But this is only a temporary solution. Try to move to API, that uses HTTPS, that supports the latest protocol, that Apple is pushing forward.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

EDIT: to be sure your HTTPS connection could be established, your API should be using these requirements:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Comment: Apparently your secured protocol is weak and does not meet Apple's requirements for TLS 1.2.